# Problems with JSON Token Middleware

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm just building a authentication platform using JSON Tokens to create a middleware only accessible after sending correct authentication. Here is server.js:

```js
// dependancies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passwordHash = require('password-hash');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./config');
var User = require('./app/models/user');

// config

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
mongoose.connect(config.database);
app.set('superSecret', config.secret);

// body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// morgan
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

app.get('/setup', function(req, res){
    var hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate('catsanddogs');
    var tommy = new User({
        user: 'Tommy Birt',
        password: hashedPassword,
        admin: false,
        MP: true,
        Position: true
    });
    // save
    tommy.save(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log('Saved');
        res.json({ success: true });
    });
});

// API routes
var apiRoutes = express.Router();

apiRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to this api.'});
});


apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){
    // Fine user
    User.findOne({
        user : req.body.user
    }, function(err, user) {
        // general error...
        if (err) throw err;

        // incorrect
        if(!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed: No user'});
        } else if(user) {
            if(!passwordHash.verify(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed: Incorrect Password'});        
            } else {
                // token!
                var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {});

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                });
            }
        } 
    })
});
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next){
    // Lets find our token!
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // Have we found it?
    if(token) {
        // Verify! No crackers please
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded){
            if(err) {
                // Somethings gone wrong...
                return res.json({ sucess: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token'});
            } else {
                // No errors! Yay :)
                req.decoded = decoded
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // No token Sir! Get off this train!
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Stop cheating'
        });
    }
});

apiRoutes.get('/balance', function(req, res){
    res.send("Welcome to your balance!");
});

// lets roll
app.listen(port);
console.log('We have taken off at http://localhost' + port);
```

However, whenever it is run, I use Postman to send authentication details to /api/authenticate and it gives me a token. However, whenever go to /api/balance it gives me an error for no token.

Comment: What does the request look like that fails?

Comment: {"sucess" : false, "message" : "Stop Cheating"}

Comment: How do you call with Postman? Your error is there. The rest of your code works.

Comment: Thats the response. And the request?

Comment: When I authenticate, it using the username and password in the code using POST. When I access the balance page, its simply using postman GET

Comment: It works as expected for me.